# Is $(1,0,...,0,-n^2,0,0,...) \in \ell^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

I am a bit unsure of this because if $n$ is very large then the sum would not be finite but then again the term after the nth term is $0$ onwards.

Comment: Is there only two non-zero elements of this vector?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes

Comment: yes it is. for each $n$, no matter where $-n^2$ lives , the sum of squares of all entries is finite.

Comment: Then the $\ell^2$-norm of this vector is $\sqrt{1+n^4}$, which is clearly finite.

Comment: Why would the sum not be finite if $n$ is very large?

Comment: why the dislikes? wtf!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An infinite-dimensional vector $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$ (or I guess we can just say sequence) is in $\ell^2$ iff $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} |x_k|^2 < +\infty$.  Well, no matter what the value of $n$ is in $x = (1, 0, 0, \dots, 0, -n^2, 0, 0, 0, \dots)$, we'll always have $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} |x_k|^2 = 1 + n^4$, and this is clearly finite for every integer (or real, etc.) value of $n$.

So, yes, the sequence is in $\ell^2$.

Comment: Would you say $$\langle y,x \rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {b_n a_n}{n} =0$$ where $x=(a_n)=(1, 1/2, ..., 1/n, ...)$ and $y=(b_n)=(1,0,...,0, -n^2, 0, 0,...)$? So $y \in \ell^2$ is orthogonal to $x$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, right, thanks.

Comment: @tilper Sorry the sum was meant to start at $n=1$ but anyways, there are only going to be two terms that will be non zero in this sum. $$\langle y,x \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {b_k a_k}{k} =0$$
This is when $k=1$ and when $k=n$. When $k=1$, we have $1$ don't we? and when k=n, we have -1. I cant see how you got 1/n...

Comment: That is not the usual definition of the dot product in $\ell^2$, @snowman It should just be $\sum b_na_n$.

Comment: Yes, right, I was looking at the sum and not thinking of the denominator as being the same as the index.  The term would be 1 and the sum would be 0.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I know, it was just an exam question that I was thinking about. Thanks to all.